# Loop to Open A WebPage with PhantomJS (With Different Parameters Per Loop Iteration) Not Working

Tags: javascript, phantomjs

When I try to use the following loop to open a page:

```
      console.log("Just before time, endTime and loopnumber gets declared.");
      var time, endTime;
      var loopnumber = 6;
      console.log("time declared as '"+time+"', loopnumber as '"+ loopnumber+"'");
      for (time = 1490543999999999, endTime = time - 518400000000 * 10; time > endTime; time -= 518400000000) {
        console.log("inside loop. time declared as '"+time+"', loopnumber as '"+ loopnumber+"'");
        var mintime = time - 518399999999;

        page.open('https://myactivity.google.com/item?min='+mintime+'&max='+time+'&product=5,6,7,10,11,12,13,15,19,20,25,27,28', function () {
        console.log("inside callback");
        page.render('/Users/jMac-NEW/Documents/FILEMAKER OCLC/login_test33.1_brkpoint'+loopnumber+'.png');
        fs.write('/Users/jMac-NEW/Documents/FILEMAKER OCLC/login_test33.1_brkpoint'+loopnumber+'html.html',page.content,'w');

      });
      loopnumber++;
      }
```

`console.log("inside loop. time declared as '"+time+"', loopnumber as '"+ loopnumber+"'");` gets called, but not the `console.log` inside the callback function of `page.open`. `page.render` and `fs.write` also does not work (I do not see the expected result file in my directory.)

How come?

EDIT:
If it's just because page.open doesn't have enough time, how can I give it enough time? with `setInterval()`?

EDIT2:
What I am trying to get the code to do is to call `myactivity.google.com/item` with a different set of arguments for each iteration of the loop, save the webpage as a `.png` file and an `.html` file.

Yes, I have imported `fs` before this code segment, just that it isn't shown here.

Comment: How fast does your loop iterating? (sorry, won't calculate that myself :) It's possible that `page.open` just doesn't have enought time to open a page and issue a callback.

Comment: i see. then how do I give page.open enough time?

Comment: That largely depends on what you're trying to do. Maybe edit the question with description of your task? (but keep the code to show what you've tried)

Comment: you simply load the next page before the first one is finished, that's why you will have only have 1 callback at the end. also, did you import fs `var fs = require('fs')`?

Comment: ok I have included a description @Vaviloff, and yes Alex I have imported it.

Comment: The safest way might be to do away with the `for` loop and have the call back trigger the next load. That way you will only start loading the next page when the previous page has finished

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps the easiest way is to have the next page load be trigger by the callback from the previous page load. That way you *know* that the previous page has finished loading (note however, that *loaded* doesn't necessarily mean *rendered* and if there's a bunch of Javascript running on your page to render something - like a chart for example, you still my be rendering your screen before it's finished)

Something like this:

```js
var time = 1490543999999999;
var endTime = time - 518400000000 * 10;
var mintime = time - 518399999999;

page.open('https://myactivity.google.com/item?min=' + mintime + '&max=' + time + '&product=5,6,7,10,11,12,13,15,19,20,25,27,28', callback);

function callback() {
  console.log("inside callback");
  page.render('/Users/jMac-NEW/Documents/FILEMAKER OCLC/login_test33.1_brkpoint' + loopnumber + '.png');
  fs.write('/Users/jMac-NEW/Documents/FILEMAKER OCLC/login_test33.1_brkpoint' + loopnumber + 'html.html', page.content, 'w');
  time -= 518400000000;
  if (time > endTime) {
    var mintime = time - 518399999999;
    page.open('https://myactivity.google.com/item?min=' + mintime + '&max=' + time + '&product=5,6,7,10,11,12,13,15,19,20,25,27,28', callback);
  }
}
```